# MySQL - getting sum() based on week/month numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, greatest-n-per-group

I have an expenses table called "transactions" that includes user_id, date_time and amount.

What I am trying to do is to query for sum(amount) grouped by user_id based on week number / month, eg:

1) top 10 spending users for week, say, 22 or 10

2) top 10 spending users for, say, 3rd month

I did look through the site and while there are similar SQL examples, they're mostly based on 7 day sliding windows or "last week" or "last month". I am still trying to see if I can figure it out using the MySQL docs but would appreciate any pointers that can save some time.

Thank you!

PS I am using Rails 3, maybe the framework has some built-in methods for this? The basic finders won't do...

Later edit:

I would have expected this to work, but it includes data from this week as well:

```
SELECT user_id,  sum(amount) AS t
 FROM transactions
 WHERE YEARWEEK(date_time) = YEARWEEK(now() - interval 1 week) 
group by user_id
```

Comment: firstly, what's a week to you: mon-sun? or sun-sat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solutions should guide you in the right direction. These solutions also maintain the use of any index you have set up for your `date_time` field (query remains sargable since date comparisons are done on the bare `date_time` column rather than the `date_time` column wrapped inside of a function):

```
-- Top 10 users by transaction amount for 3rd month of the year
SELECT   user_id, 
         SUM(amount) AS t
FROM     transactions
WHERE    date_time >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-03-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
         date_time <  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-03-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY t DESC
LIMIT    10
```

^ Here we are getting the sum of transactions by user that occured in the 3rd month of the year (or March). Replace the occurrences of `03` with whichever month of the year you wish to retrieve the sum from.

---

```
-- Top 10 users by transaction amount for 20th week of the year
SELECT   user_id,
         SUM(amount) AS t
FROM     transactions
WHERE    date_time >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 7-(DAYOFWEEK(MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 7))-1)) +
                      INTERVAL 20     WEEK AND
         date_time <  MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 7-(DAYOFWEEK(MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 7))-1)) +
                      INTERVAL 20 + 1 WEEK
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY t DESC
LIMIT    10
```

^ This solution might *look* clunky at first glance, but what it's doing is it's emulating the `YEARWEEK()` function so as to keep the `date_time` column outside of any kind of function wrap (so it can utilize the index as mentioned previously).

Replace occurrences of `20` with whichever week of the year you wish to retrieve the sum from.

Comment: I think you're missing a hyphen before the '01-01' in the concats.  You could also replace the entire inner UNIONS with something like...  SELECT DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), interval 7-(DAYOFWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'))-1) day);   Needs a bit more testing, but you get the idea

Comment: @carpii thanks for pointing that out, and yes I knew there had to be a better way (I just needed the date of the first Sunday of the current year) but it was 3 in the morning when I wrote it hehe. I made a slightly more concise version of your suggestion, so thank you for that.

Comment: That is a nice solution, thank you for posting! I'm going to wrap this into some private methods and add the month/week numbers as parameters :)